# Drivers are not installed on D-Link DWA-137 ver1.03

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, wifi-driver

When i install any driver on my adapter i get this error get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iOp1.png):

```
Failed to load the driver for this device. The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)

Cannot verify the digital signature of this file. The signing certificate for this file has been revoked.
```

This adapter worked for me for about 5 years and today it stopped working giving this error. I tried to install both official and non-official drivers, but nothing helped.

Comment: The issue is in the second line of the error: the driver trying to be loaded no longer has a valid digital signature since the certificate that signed it has been revoked. There are two options for resolving this: download the driver from DLink's site, which will have an updated driver signature, or _only if DLink no longer offers a downloadable driver_ **AND** _you 100% trust the current driver and know it hasn't been tampered with_, create a code signing certificate and sign it yourself, which I cover [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46713936/6819406)